# Punctuation of Isn't it

Tags: periods, question-mark

How would you punctuate the phrase

> It's a beautiful day, isn't it?

Would you use a question mark or period at the end?

My intent is to make it rhetorical. The full example is:

> She woke up alone, saw the sun streaming through her window, and proclaimed "Isn't it a beautiful day"

Comment: How is the question being asked? Is it a legitimate query, or is it cynical and rhetorical?

Comment: Whether the tag question is intended to solicit an answer or is rhetorical (with the sense 'as you must agree'), the convention is always to use a question mark.  ' ... exclaimed rhetorically ...?' is unambiguous.

Answer (score 1):

Use a question mark at the end, not a period. The short clause at the end of the statement changes it into a question.

In "It's a beautiful day, isn't it?", "isn't it?" is the question tag.

You use a question tag to see if the listener agrees with what you have said.

For example, in "He went to the office, didn't he?", "didn't he?" is the question tag.

In "He didn't go to the office, did he?", "did he?" is the question tag. You think he didn't go to the office, but you want to confirm it.

Two more examples:

"He has eaten his breakfast, hasn't he?"

"He hasn't eaten his breakfast, has he?"

Comment: This isn't necessarily true—although you're right in general. If it's a miserable day out, and something says the sentence in a *rhetorical* fashion, not expecting an answer (a muttered statement, without any rising inflection in their voice), it's still a question, but it could be punctuated with a period. It's the same as the rhetorical question "Really." More context should really be provided in the question here.

Comment: I think it is hard to avoid the conclusion that a tag question is a question - however spoken.

Comment: @Jasson Bassford Your justification for ' ... it's still a question, but it could be punctuated with a period'? I'd like this to be acceptable as it adds versatility, but I've never seen such a licensing. Question marks with declarative questions, certainly.